# Why doesn't GCC need WinMain entrypoint when specifying a C-file as part of the input?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

> Why doesn't GCC need `WinMain` entrypoint when specifying a C-file as part of the input?

I've a small assembly file called `qt2.s` that just add a pair of integers. This file has `tigermain` as a global symbol (the function of the file).

If I try to compile this file by itself, then I get the following error:

```
C:\dev\MinGWx64\bin>gcc-4.8.3.exe qt2.o -o qt2.exe
c:/dev/mingwx64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The C-runtime of GCC cannot find global symbol `WinMain`.

However, if I type:

```
C:\dev\MinGWx64\bin>gcc-4.8.3.exe runtime.c qt2.s -o qt2.exe
```

Everything works just fine. Here `runtime.c` is a plain C-file containing the declaration: `int tigermain(void *, int64_t);`

Comment: Pass `-v` to `gcc` to understand what is going on.

Comment: `C:\dev\MinGWx64\bin>gcc-4.8.3.exe qt2.o -o qt2.exe` is not compiling the `.s`, it is linking the object. How do you compile it?